# The method 'of' isn't defined for the type 'ThemeProvider'. in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-provider, flutter-theme

I am Beginner to Flutter just following the [YouTube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZfSiFtT0z_I&list=PLXCknapk5keZEmGuQnzhPbGsmfuK2zPzK&index=1) on building User Profile while doing everything is OK but Theme Provider gave me the error I didn't understand What's going on can You guys help me, the error is `The method 'of' isn't defined for the type 'ThemeProvider'`, I am getting error at

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = UserPreferences.getUser();
    return ThemeProvider(
      initTheme: user.isDarkMode ?  MyThemes.darkTheme : MyThemes.lightTheme,
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) => MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeProvider.of(context),
          title: title,
          home:  const ProfilePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

and full code is so long so I Attaching [github link](https://github.com/pshanmukha/Flutter_User_Profile) for reference, Thanking You Advance. [image: ThemeProvider error]

After updating theme_provider in dependency I got 2 more errors below I attached a [image: theme_provider error]screenshot of it.

Comment: Did you read this link: https://pub.dev/packages/theme_provider

Answer (score 0):

It is **themeOf** not **of**.
You can check the official docs [here](https://pub.dev/packages/theme_provider)

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = UserPreferences.getUser();
    return ThemeProvider(
      initTheme: user.isDarkMode ?  MyThemes.darkTheme : MyThemes.lightTheme,
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) => MaterialApp(
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
          theme: ThemeProvider.themeOf(context),
          title: title,
          home:  const ProfilePage(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey @Saral still getting error, The method 'themeOf' isn't defined for the type 'ThemeProvider'

Comment: Did you add theme_provider in your dependency and import it in your file?

Comment: Because I cannot see that in your github code

Comment: No, but now I added theme_provider in dependency and import it, and now I got 2 more errors I will update the screenshot of the error u can see it above.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't skip reading Documentation.Keep on mind your Module docs.**

This is the sample of your package owner.Be careful check.

```
    ThemeProvider(
          initTheme: initTheme,
   ---->  builder: (context, myTheme) {
            return MaterialApp(
              title: 'Flutter Demo',
        ----> theme: myTheme,
              home: MyHomePage(),
            );
          }),
        ),
```

Comment: Can you explain what is 'myTheme' please?

Answer (score 0):

i believe its been change to

```
ThemeModelInheritedNotifier.of(context).theme.brightness
```

you can use a builder in you material app and pass theme throught it as done in the documentaion [here](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_theme_switcher/example)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it after hours trying...
Uff..

Lets go, I don't know what happened with this package, but have an error.

But for our happiness, I resolved it with a little trap... rsrs

We need tell to "theme: ," a context of ThemeProvider, but the library is bugged.

Then, I tried it.

tell to theme: same code that initTheme.

```
theme: user.isDarkMode ? MyThemes.darkTheme : MyThemes.lightTheme,
```

is worth.

put the same code that "initTheme: xxxxx," in "theme: xxxxx".

Worthed for me.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const user = UserPreferences.myUser;
    return ThemeProvider(
      initTheme: user.isDarkMode ? MyThemes.darkTheme : MyThemes.lightTheme,
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) => MaterialApp(
          title: 'MyTitle',
          theme: user.isDarkMode ? MyThemes.darkTheme : MyThemes.lightTheme,
          scrollBehavior: SBehavior(),
          home: const SplashArt(),
          debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```